# Array not re-rendering even after this.setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set up a searchbar as the child component and pass it two props, one is the array of cards that I am rendering and the other is function, which should setState as the search field changes.

```
<Searchbar quesCards={questionCards} filter={this.filter} /> :
```

Now this `questionCards` is a state variable containing the array of cards to be displayed.

```
questionCards.push(
     <QuestionCard
        id={i}
        question={question.question}
        answer={question.answer}
        isMarked={question.isMarked}
        isPublished={question.isPublished}
        validity={question.validity}
        category={question.category}
      />
  )

this.setState({ questionCards, newCards: questionCards, loading: false });
```

Here `<QuestionCard />` is another component, but I believe it has nothing to do with the issue.

Inside my child component, I call `this.props.filter` with the filtered results like this:

```
handleChange = name => event => {
  //filtering the data ...
  this.props.filter(newCards);
}
```

This I do inside onChange function of `<Searchbar/>` 
Back in the Parent Component,

```
filter = (newCards) => {
  console.log(newCards); //displays the desired result
  this.setState({ newCards }); //the state changes, but is not rendered on screen
}
```

After this setState, the component should re-render with the new results. But it doesn't happen so.
Please note that it is `newCards` which is getting displayed, since the beginning and `questionCards` is used only to pass as `prop`
I have already tried `this.forceUpdate`
Also, **if I console log inside the function `filter`, `newCards` contains correct results, but it is not getting re-rendered after `this.setState({ newCards })`**

Comment: So searchBar component takes an array of questions, the filter what does it do? Filter by property?

Comment: searchbar filters the result on the basis of question and the input in the searchbar.
`ques.includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase());`
<br/>The `prop` filter on the other hand is for the function. As you can see, `filter={this.filter}`. So `this.props.filter(newCards)` invokes the function `filter` back in the parent component

Comment: If you send filter back up will it just filter the array or just re-query?

Comment: The filtering takes place all in the child component and the filtered result is passed as argument to the function, ready to be setState with, in the parent component

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your data flow is inefficient.

Your filter input within searchBar, should update some filter state (locally). It looks like just need to filter the questions from your filter state.

The consumer of `<SearchBar />` does not need to know the filter.

```
const list = questions.filter(item => (
  // item.name[enter_property] === this.state.filter
))
```

Then just `.map()` over list.

—

What condition are you matching? A specific property or multiple of them?

Answer (score 0):

You are generating QuestionCard like this

```
questionCards.push(
     <QuestionCard
        id={i}
        question={question.question}
        answer={question.answer}
        isMarked={question.isMarked}
        isPublished={question.isPublished}
        validity={question.validity}
        category={question.category}
      />
  )
```

But ,your updating the newCards state variable ,can u check that?

If its not resolved , can u post your full code.

Comment: `this.setState({ questionCards, newCards: questionCards, loading: false });` did you miss out this line? Also I am displaying `newCards` variable since the beginning